# Multithreaded Zip file reader

Tags: java, multithreading, zip

I had a requirement for Multithreaded Zip file reader for my ongoing project.When i say multithreaded I mean for example there are two threads and both try to read the same file so I need something which creates Inputstreams on two seperate threads so the zip file dosen't become corrupted. I would like to know that if there is any existing code available which can do the job as I don't want to reinvent the wheel.

Also it would be good that the code just give me new instances of buffered reader created on separated threads so that I can just used the reader and carry on with my work. In addition the code must also take care of the thread pool and remove himself from thread  pool when work done.

Comment: Disk IO is a bottleneck so you can't have several streams to the same file, and thus I don't think you'll find a very good solution for this project, given that it's reading from a single file. Some OSs only allow one accessor at a time, in any case.

Comment: wat about Just create separate FileInputStream for each thread.

Comment: how i can create separate FileInputStream for each thread. can u elaborate on that. my thread knowledge is pretty weak.

Comment: Just open the file twice, once in each thread. There's no mystery about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First off**, as I wrote in my comment up top, disk IO is a bottleneck and sometimes you can't access a file when theres's already one open file descriptor.

It is quite a question to impose, but as some food for thought you could open a `FileInputStream` in each thread and then synchronize between them the position you're reading from.

Assuming we have two streams:

```
FileInputStream f1 = new FileInputStream("test.zip"),
  f2 = new FileInputStream("test.zip");
```

You can read as you usually do and then `skip(long n)` after reading some bytes in one thread. Say you read 10 bytes using `f1` then you'd want to execute `f2.skip(10)` before reading in `f2` because it would return the same bytes otherwise. Assuming this is what you want, of course.

After reading the header of the Zip file you can determine where all the individual parts of the archive are located within the file and read those exact blocks separately. But, as Dave Newton correctly states, you should use well-defined libraries for reading the Zip files, though.

Comment: Why would you do zip operations by hand when zip classes already exist?

Comment: I wouldn't, I'm just trying to explain some basics.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest reading up on multhreading in Java first - it's the best way to learn about the problem, which will lead you to understand a better path to the solution (if you insist on attempting multithreaded IO. A quick Google search brought me [these](http://www.google.co.uk/search?gcx=c&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=java+multithreading) results. However, I do agree on what netrom said.